# Is my biome/climate map realistic?

Tags: internal-consistency, climate, map-making

just looking for a quick accuracy check of my continent's biome/climate map. This continent is on a planet much like Earth and it is about the size of Eurasia. It is situated in the southern hemisphere. The mountain range in the temperate forest area is a very old weathered range similar to the Appalachians, hence I left out a rain shadow.

Just looking for any major inaccuracies that need to be fixed.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Not my field of expertise, but I'd have expected your inland mediterranean-like sea to have more mediterraneanness than you've given it.

Comment: Just due to size most of that continent will be desert, water can only travel so far inland. Also you want to look inot hadley cells as latitude has a huge effect on on local biomes.

Comment: Just a question, what software did you use to make this map ?:)

Answer (score 3):

You have a huge continent which is also almost square, so its center will have very continental climate, one which tries to maintain either -30C or +30C at all times.

This is your "temperate grassland" which instead would have climate like Mongolia or Kazakhstan.

Also, the green area in the desert's upper left corner should be flipped - it will get its rains from air coming from sea and captured by mountains.

Comment: Also, I think that on such a large continent, there should be much more features - patches of this climate and that climate.

Comment: I forgot about this but just happened upon it again. Thanks for the feedback. A climate like the eurasian steppe (mongolia/kazakhstan) was exactly what I was going for with the "temperate grassland" area. Those areas are in fact in temperate zones and they are arid grasslands.

Answer (score 1):

I scratch my head at seeing that along the tropic you have desert and tropical rainforest, and that you transition from the tropical rainforest to the temperate forest with nothing in between when you go more to the South.

That seems quite odd.

Comment: This does make sense if western wind always blows, and it loses all its steam over rainforest and then savannah.

Comment: Why does this seem odd? What zone is there between tropical and temperate? I didn't feel the need to make a separate "subtropical" forest as that's not really a thing. If you look at east Asia, you will see that it goes from temperate forest in China to tropical rainforest in southeast asia with nothing in between.

Answer (score 0):

I have only one suggestion: with the amount of 'squeezing' of the tectonic plates you have here, you should probably create a solid volcanic trench on the other side.